# unique dictionary by scraping several webs

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am scraping several websites with scrapy and my output creates a list of dicts (one per website). I would like my output to only create one dict. I've tried to use meta but I don't understand it well and I can't get it to work.

This is my code:

```
class TransferSpider(scrapy.Spider):     
    # name of the spider
    name = 'transfers'
    # list of urls to scraping
    start_urls = ['https://www.transfermarkt.es/transfers/transfertagedetail/statistik/top/land_id_zu/0/land_id_ab/0/leihe//datum/2022-07-10/sort//plus/1',
                 'https://www.transfermarkt.es/transfers/transfertagedetail/statistik/top/land_id_zu/0/land_id_ab/0/leihe//datum/2022-07-10/sort//plus/1/page/2']

    custom_settings={"FEEDS":{"players.json" : {"format" : "json", 'encoding':'utf-8', 'indent':4}}}
 
    
    def parse(self, response):
        # Extract all text from table
        data = response.xpath("//*[@id='yw1']/table/tbody//table//text()").extract()
        # Delete space
        data = map(str.strip, data)
        # Take no empty elements
        data = list(filter(lambda x: (x != ''), data))
        #print(data)
        yield {
            'names': data[0::6],
            'position': data[1::6],
            'origin_club': data[2::6],
            'leage_origin_club': data[3::6],
            'new_club': data[4::6],
            'leage_new_club': data[5::6]
        }
```

Probably the solution isn't very difficult but I can't get it

The output I want is:

```
{
    Names:[list whit names],
    Position:[list with positions]
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not specify the desired dict outcome... and nobody can stop you from using complex solutions. However, the job can be done in a straightforward manner, with python, requests, BeautifulSoup and pandas:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

final_list = []

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.60 Safari/537.17'}

for x in range(1, 7):
    r = requests.get(f'https://www.transfermarkt.es/transfers/transfertagedetail/statistik/top/land_id_zu/0/land_id_ab/0/leihe//datum/2022-07-10/sort//plus/2/page/{x}', headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    big_table = soup.select('table.items>tbody>tr')
    for row in big_table:
        name = row.find_all('td',  recursive=False)[0].select('td')[1]
        position = row.find_all('td',  recursive=False)[0].select('td')[2]
        age = row.find_all('td',  recursive=False)[1]
        nationality = row.find_all('td',  recursive=False)[2].select_one('img')['alt']
        origin_club = row.find_all('td',  recursive=False)[3].select('td')[1]
        origin_club_league = row.find_all('td',  recursive=False)[3].select('td')[2]
        new_club = row.find_all('td',  recursive=False)[4].select('td')[1]
        new_club_league = row.find_all('td',  recursive=False)[4].select('td')[2]
        value_when_transferred = row.find_all('td',  recursive=False)[5]
        cost = row.find_all('td',  recursive=False)[6]
        final_list.append((name.text.strip(), age.text.strip(), 
                           position.text.strip(), nationality, 
                           origin_club.text.strip(), origin_club_league.text.strip(), 
                           new_club.text.strip(), new_club_league.text.strip(), 
                           value_when_transferred.text.strip(),cost.text.strip()))
final_df = pd.DataFrame(final_list, columns = ['Name', 'Age', 'Position', 'Nationality', 
                        'Origin Club', 'Origin Club league', 'New Club', 'New Club League', 
                        'Value when transferred', 'Cost'])
final_df
```

This dataframe can be made into a dict:

```
final_dict = final_df.to_dict()
final_dict
```

EDIT: As you are now confirming the desired final dictionary, you can do:

```
final_dict = {}
final_dict['Names'] = final_df['Name'][:2].tolist()
final_dict['Ages'] = final_df['Age'][:2].tolist()
final_dict['Positions'] = final_df['Position'][:2].tolist()
final_dict
```

Which will return :

```
{'Names': ['Neco Williams', 'Omar Richards'],
 'Ages': ['21', '24'],
 'Positions': ['Lateral derecho', 'Lateral izquierdo']}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your posted tag `scrapy` and output as dictionary, you can try the next example:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class TransferSpider(scrapy.Spider):     
    name = 'transfers'
    start_urls = ['https://www.transfermarkt.es/transfers/transfertagedetail/statistik/top/land_id_zu/0/land_id_ab/0/leihe//datum/2022-07-10/sort//plus/1/page/'+str(x)+'' for x in range(1,3)]


    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 1,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1,
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        "FEEDS": {'data.json': {'format': 'json'}},
        "FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING": "utf-8",
        "INDENT":4
          }

 
    def parse(self, response):
        #for tr in response.xpath('//*[@class="items"]/tbody/tr'):
           
        yield {
            'names': response.xpath('//*[@class="items"]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tr[1]/td[2]/a/text()').getall(),
            'position': response.xpath('//*[@class="items"]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tr[2]/td/text()').getall(),
            'origin_club':response.xpath('//*[@class="items"]/tbody/tr/td[4]/table/tr/td[2]/a/text()').getall(),
            'leage_origin_club':response.xpath('//*[@class="items"]/tbody/tr/td[4]/table/tr[2]/td/a/text()').getall(),
            'new_club': response.xpath('//*[@class="items"]/tbody/tr/td[5]/table/tr[1]/td[2]/a/text()').getall(),
            'leage_new_club': response.xpath('//*[@class="items"]/tbody/tr/td[5]/table/tr[2]/td/a/text()').getall()
        }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(TransferSpider)
    process.start()
```

**Output:**

```
 {'names': ['Diego Vita', 'Julani Archibald', 'Alessio Benedetti', 'Santino Misale', 'Panagiotis Arnaoutoglou', 'Tauã', 'Igor Zeetti', 'Matías Nahuel', 'Hakob 
Hakobyan', 'Vojtech Brak', 'Jordi Calavera', 'Igor Kurylo', 'Aleksey Chubukin', 'Adrián Jiménez', 'Jesús del Amo', 'Giovanni Romano', 'Giuseppe Lopez', 'Sagas Tambi', 'Pedro Justiniano', 'Insar Salakhetdinov', 'Francesco Mele', 'Sina Moridi', 'Julen Monreal', 'Mahmoud Motlaghzadeh', 'Katriel Islamaj'], 'position': 
['Extremo derecho', 'Portero', 'Mediocentro', 'Lateral izquierdo', 'Lateral izquierdo', 'Extremo izquierdo', 'Defensa central', 'Extremo izquierdo', 'Lateral 
izquierdo', 'Defensa central', 'Lateral derecho', 'Defensa central', 'Defensa central', 'Defensa central', 'Defensa central', 'Extremo derecho', 'Delantero centro', 'Pivote', 'Defensa central', 'Pivote', 'Pivote', 'Pivote', 'Defensa central', 'Mediocentro', 'Mediocentro'], 'origin_club': ['Sanremese ', 'Santa Lucia FC', 'Arezzo', 'Gioiese', 'PASA Irodotos', 'PT Prachuap FC', 'Montespaccato', 
'CD Tenerife', 'FC Urartu ', 'Usti nad Labem', 'Girona FC', 'Agrobiznes V.', 'FK Saransk', 'CD Toledo', 'Ast. Vlachioti', 'Portici', 'Brindisi', 'Bnei Yehuda', 'Coimbra', 'Biolog', 'Chieti FC', 'Foolad', 'UE Costa Brava', 'Sanat Naft', 'Real Forte'], 'leage_origin_club': ['Serie D - A', 'Premier League
```

... so on

Comment: Tanks F.Hoque, but I'd like output like {'names':[list of names], 'position':[list of positions]...} how I can do it?